# How to open different emacs version from the shell?

Tags: bash, homebrew, emacs

I have two versions of emacs on my machine. One came preinstalled and I have just installed a newer version with homebrew.

[image]

If I type `emacs` in the terminal, the old version runs. If I type `emacs-24.4` then the new version runs. What do I have to do to ensure typing just `emacs` runs the 24.4 version and not the older version?

Comment: What is your PATH?

Comment: My $PATH is quite long, but it includes /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.4/bin/

Comment: Not the best way I think ;) Homebrew should have links from /usr/local/bin to the cellar and then /usr/local.bin is in your path. However the issue is is is which directory that contains an executable emacs is first in the $PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this for just Emacs, use

```
alias emacs=/usr/local/bin/emacs
```

in your shell startup file which will make Emacs always run Homebrew emacs instead of whatever is first in your `$PATH`.

But the better way to do this is to make your shell always look for Homebrew versions of commands first, by putting `/usr/local/bin` **first**, or at least early, in your `$PATH`.

So if your `$PATH` is set like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

change it to this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

`/usr/local/bin` is a directory containing symlinks to all Homebrew-installed commands, Emacs included, and your shell starts at the beginning of the `$PATH` to figure out what executable to use, so putting it first will in effect choose the Homebrew emacs first.

One last thing - please remove `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.4/bin` from your `$PATH`. It's going to break when the next version of Emacs comes out. If you use `/usr/local/bin` instead, Homebrew will automatically manage the symlinks when you update things.